# Want to navigate between screens in one tab in react native

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

I am working on a project that I want to switch between screens in one tab. for example I have 4 bottom tabs. and from the 1st tab, I want to move to another screen or component inside 1st tab

[image: Example Picture]

From this picture, I want to move to another screen or component by staying inside 1st tab.
Could anyone help me to get the possible way.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to nest navigators which is a basic feature of [react-native-navigation](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/nesting-navigators/#navigating-to-a-screen-in-a-nested-navigator).

This is described in the documentation [here](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/nesting-navigators/).

Navigating to a screen works as usual as it is described in the documentation [here](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/nesting-navigators/#navigating-to-a-screen-in-a-nested-navigator).

Here is a minimal working example for which I have made a working [snack](https://snack.expo.dev/@pgrepds/simple-nested-navigation).

**App.js**

```js
import React from 'react';

import {NavigationContainer} from '@react-navigation/native';

import Tabs from './Tabs'

export default function App() {

   return (
      <NavigationContainer>
         <Tabs />
      </NavigationContainer>
   )
}
```

**Tabs.js** with 2 Tabs

```js
import React from 'react';

import {createBottomTabNavigator} from '@react-navigation/bottom-tabs';

import Home from './Home.js'
import Profile from './Profile.js'

const Tab = createBottomTabNavigator();

function Tabs() {
  return (
    <Tab.Navigator>
      <Tab.Screen name="Home" component={Home} />
      <Tab.Screen name="Profile" component={Profile} />
    </Tab.Navigator>
  );
}

export default Tabs;
```

**Home.js** a `StackNavigator`

```js
import React from 'react';

import {createNativeStackNavigator} from '@react-navigation/native-stack';

import ScreenA from './ScreenA.js'
import ScreenB from './ScreenB.js'

const Stack = createNativeStackNavigator()

function Home() {
    return <Stack.Navigator>
       <Stack.Screen name="" component={ScreenA} options={{headerShown: false}} />
       <Stack.Screen name="ScreenB" component={ScreenB} />
    </Stack.Navigator>
}

export default Home;
```

**ScreenA.js**

```js
import React from 'react'
import { View, Button } from 'react-native'

function ScreenA(props) {

  return <View>
      <Button title="NavigateToScreenBInTabHone" onPress={() => props.navigation.navigate('ScreenB')}>
      </Button>
  </View>
}

export default ScreenA;
```

**ScreenB.js**

```js
import React from 'react'
import { View } from 'react-native'

function ScreenB() {

  return <View></View>
}

export default ScreenB;
```

**Profile.js**

```js
import React from 'react'
import { View } from 'react-native'

function Profile() {

  return <View></View>
}

export default Profile;
```